# Autocomplete in Solr is case sensitive

Tags: solr

I have implemented a autocomplete component in which the auto complete becomes case sensitive.I have added the following piece of code and it works case sensitive.How to make this case insensitive.

```
 <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
      <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>      
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">name_s</str>
        <str name="weightField">price</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
      </lst>
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" 
                    startup="lazy" >
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      </lst>
      <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
      </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: Can you post the details of name_s field?

Comment: Do you want me to post schema.xml or solrconfig.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this running by adding the following in schema.xml.
In schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">
          <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
          <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```